# Javascript passing variable from one function to another and triggering it through a btn

Tags: javascript, function, scope

First the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/p9yfczh7/1/
/edit/
Fiddle two without the "var", still doesn't work:
https://jsfiddle.net/p9yfczh7/2/

```
(function(){

var f;

two(1, 2); // 2 is the future "I need this"

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener("click", function() {
            one("A-test", "B-test", "C-test", f);
        }, false);
    }

function three(f) {
    // edit remove, its a debug leftover - console.log("three:" + f);
    return f;
}

function one(a, b, c, f) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
    console.log(f); // how do I console.log "I need this" here?
}

function two(e, f) { // I need both arguments
    var someVar = e;
    var f = "I need this";
    three(f);
 }

})();
```

html:

```
<button id="clickMe">ClickMe</button>
```

So, what I want to achieve is to on click of `Click Me` print out `I need this` from `function one`. The button is the problem, since if it weren't for the button I could just put `one("A-test", "B-test", "C-test", f);` in `function three` and it would work.

I need `function two` to be a separate function since it is also used elsewhere and I also need all those parameters (well probably apart from "b" and "c").

I believe this to be a scope problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Oh, and please no jQuery.

/edit/
Doing:
var f = "I need this";
two(1); // and deleting the "2" from `function two`
doesn't do the trick, i need to pass the second value as an argument.

and doing window.f is not a good solution either
/edit 2/
Thanks for all the helpful answers, some of them work in fiddle but when I try to copy the logic into my real code the function does not work. This got overcomplicated for what I want to achieve, I will do some more tests tomorrow but I think I need to approach this matter from a totally different way.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In function two do not use the var statement...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3tj6sfx5/1/

Comment: Note that your local variable `f` in `two()` is masking the `f` you declared earlier, which also contributes to (what I assume is) the problem.

Comment: When you set `var f = "I need this"` in `two()`, do you expect it to set the value of `var f` in the outer scope? Because presently you're just assigning that value to the local variable, which disappears as soon as you leave the scope of `two()`.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, you're saying you only want it to say "I need this" and the other logs if the button is clicked? In which case, you need only call function two from inside your onclick listener. Updated answer....

Comment: @Serlite I want to somehow pass the new `f` from `two()` onto the button click that calls `one()`.

Comment: @Baki I see. To clarify, you're not presently using the second argument in `two(e, f)` for anything, right?

Comment: I guess I should have made it more explicit, in my real example I'm actually using both parameters. I will edit my original question to make it clear.
_edit_  
I've actually said that in my second section in the original question

Comment: If you don't declare what f is, then console will say it undefined of course!

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion :

in function two you can return three(f) and then call two('',f) instead of just f in your callback function :

```
(function(){

var f;

two(1, 2); // 2 is the future "I need this"

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener("click", function() {
            one("A-test", "B-test", "C-test", two('',f);
        }, false);
    }

function three(f) {
    console.log("three:" + f);
    return f;
}

function one(a, b, c, f) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
    console.log(f); // how do I console.log "I need this" here?
}

function two(e, f) {
    var someVar = e;
    var f = "I need this";
    return three(f);
 }

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve the desired behaviour would be to use a different variable name (ie. Not `f`) for the variable you want to use in the click callback function. Going by your current naming convention...how about `g`? So your JavaScript would change to:

```
(function(){

var g;

two(1, 2); // 2 is the future "I need this"

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener("click", function() {
            one("A-test", "B-test", "C-test", g);
        }, false);
}
function three(f) {
    console.log("three:" + f);
    return f;
}

function one(a, b, c, f) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
    console.log(f); // how do I console.log "I need this" here?
}

function two(e, f) {
    var someVar = e;
    g = "I need this";
    three(g);
}

})();
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9yfczh7/3/) to demonstrate. Now, you can avoid potential masking issues by using different names for your variables. Note how I left the second argument in `two()` in, since you said you'd be using that for something else.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Removed var statement in function two so you use it as a global variable instead of creating a new local variable. Oh and also get rid of the second param in your function call of two() so it looks like "two(1)" and also adjusted in function.

```
(function(){

var f;


    document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener("click", function() {
            one("A-test", "B-test", "C-test", two(1));
        }, false);


function three(f) {
    console.log("three:" + f);
    return f;
}

function one(a, b, c, f) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
    console.log(f); // how do I console.log "I need this" here?
}

function two(e) {
    var someVar = e;
    f = "I need this";
    return three(f);
 }

})();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not work and I also need two parameters in `two()`

Comment: @Baki I removed the window onload function and I get the following printout in console after clicking the button three:I need this
/_display/ (line 33)
A-test
/_display/ (line 38)
B-test
/_display/ (line 39)
C-test
/_display/ (line 40)
I need this